# Smart Pointers in a language that compiles to C

Tags: c, code-generation, smart-pointers

I'm writing a simple language that compiles to C, and I want to implement smart pointers. I need a bit of help with that though, as I can't seem to think of how I would go around it, or if it's even possible. My current idea is to free the pointer when it goes out of scope, the compiler would handle inserting the frees. This leads to my questions:

- How would I tell when a pointer has gone out of scope?
- Is this even possible?

The compiler is written in C, and compiles to C. I thought that I could check when the pointer goes out of scope at compile-time, and insert a free into the generated code for the pointer, i.e:

```
// generated C code.
int main() {
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
    *x = 5;
    free(x); // inserted by the compiler
}
```

The scoping rules (in my language) are exactly the same as C.

My current setup is your standard compiler, first it lexes the file contents, then it parses the token stream, semantically analyzes it, and then generates code to C. The parser is a recursive descent parser. I would like to avoid something that happens on execution, i.e. I want it to be a compile-time check that has little to no overhead, and isn't full blown garbage collection.

Comment: What have you tried already? What language and what runtime do you know? How does it implement smart pointers? What's wrong with that?

Comment: Implement the smart pointers in your language, not in the C obviously.  As we don't know your language, we can't tell you how scoping rules work in your language, other than the fact that yes it's probably possible.

Comment: My question is that I don't even know if it's possible, and I can't think of how I would implement it. I want to insert a free when the pointer goes out of scope, but I don't know how to tell if a pointer has gone out of scope. The language is written in C.

Comment: Wait, you're writing a program that converts C code to C code?  Seems kind of pointless doesn't it?  Also, C often has lots of pointers that should _not_ be freed when they go out of scope, so that's kind of a non-starter.  You need to have a smart-pointer type, or several.

Comment: Oops, kind of an ambiguous statement, the compiler is written in C, i.e it's a language that generates C code as opposed to compiling to assembly, or another immediate representation.

Comment: This sounds pretty similar to automatic reference counting in Objective C, so you might get some ideas by researching that. In fact, a simple version of Objective C's ARC is probably the easiest path you have: automatically increment a reference count on initialization/copy, and automatically decrement when going out of scope. In C, that would turn into some kind of ref_add and ref_dec calls that would get inserted at the proper points. You can even find the C source for ARC if you want ideas on how to efficiently implement said functions.

Comment: Reference counting adds a tiny amount of overhead, but is by _far_ the easiest way to do what the OP wants.  Though he'll have to allocate more than the "original code" asked for.

Comment: @Corbin It's pretty much exactly the same as ARC, however when I tried to research it, people told me that the counting is some weird LLVM specific thing, and I didn't understand when references were added or removed, but I know now! However, how would I tell when it goes out of scope? And it does add overhead, but only on compile time, whereas if it was on execution it would basically be garbage collection I think?

Comment: @user2588174 How you know it goes out of scope depends on the specifications of your language. That's something you'll have to figure out as the language designer with regards to the semantics of scope in your language.

Comment: @Corbin Hmm, problem is I'm doing this to learn more about compilers, so I don't really know myself (I'm a noob to compiler development), but I can say that the scoping rules are exactly the same as C.

Comment: As Mooing Duck says, this isn't a C question. You have to resolve this issue at some intermediate stage of compilation that happens *before* you reach C code. There's no reason to assume that one input language statement = exactly one output language statement. (similarly, there's no reason to use C scopes at all if it's an output language)

Comment: @user2588174 In that case, go look up the specification of scope in C. The general gist of it though is that something goes out of scope when it's declaration is no longer contained in the executing block or the thing containing it goes out of scope. To (way) over simplify it, a variable is in scope once it's declared and out of scope once execution leaves the braces around its declaration (`{ }`). Example: `{ int x; /* begin scope of x */ { char y; /* begin scope of y */ float z; /* begin scope of z */ /*end scope of y and z */ } } /* end scope of x */`

Comment: I still don't understand programmatically how you would determine if a scope has been left based on the way that scopes work in my language. I was thinking I could have a list of Scope objects, each Scope objects contains a list of pointers that were defined in that scope (as nodes), and when the scope is entered, a new scope object is added to that scope list, when the scope is exited, the scopes pointers are freed and is removed from the list? Does that sound silly, is there a better way, or? Slight edit, the scope list would be a stack, and that scope is popped from the stack?

Comment: Adding a scope object is usually a _terrible_ idea.  The simplest idea is just "all local variables go out of scope when the function ends". Is that applicable in your language?  How do scopes work in your language?  Wait, your comment makes it look like you're mixing up your language and your compiler again.  Try to keep them straight in your head and in comments.  In the _compiler_, yes, the scope could probably be implemented as a stack of "scope objects".

Comment: @MooingDuck Sorry I'm really tired and partially sleep deprived :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For functions, each `{` starts a new scope, and each `}` closes the corresponding scope.  When a `}` is reached, the variables inside that block go out-of-scope.  Members of structs go out of scope when the struct instance goes out of scope.  There's a couple exceptions, such as temporary objects go out-of-scope at the next `;`, and compilers silently put `for` loops inside their own block scope.

```
struct thing {
   int member;
};

int foo;

int main() {
   thing a;
   {
       int b = 3;

       for(int c=0; c<b; ++c) {
          int d = rand(); //the return value of rand goes out of scope after assignment
       } //d and c go out of scope here

   } //b goes out of scope here
}//a and its members go out of scope here
//globals like foo go out-of-scope after main ends
```

C++ tries *really* hard to destroy objects in the opposite order they're constructed, you should probably do that in your language too.

(This is all from my knowledge of C++, so it might be *slightly* different from C, but I don't think it is)

---

As for memory, you'll probably want to do a little magic behind the scenes.  Whenever the user mallocs memory, you replace it with something that allocates *more* memory, and "hide" a reference count in the extra space.  It's easiest to do that at the beginning of the allocation, and to keep alignment guarantees, you use something akin to this:

```
 typedef union {
     long double f;
     void* v;
     char* c;
     unsigned long long l;
 } bad_alignment;

 void* ref_count_malloc(int bytes)
 {
     void* p = malloc(bytes + sizeof(bad_alignment)); //does C have sizeof?
     int* ref_count = p;
     *ref_count = 1; //now is 1 pointer pointing at this block
     return p + sizeof(bad_alignment);
 }
```

When they copy a pointer, you silently add something akin to this before the copy

```
 void copy_pointer(void* from, void* to) {
     if (from != NULL) 
         ref_count_free(free); //no longer points at previous block
     bad_alignment* ref_count = to-sizeof(bad_alignment);
     ++*ref_count; //one additional pointing at this block
 }
```

And when they free or a pointer goes out of scope, you add/replace the call with something like this:

```
 void ref_count_free(void* ptr) {
     if(ptr) {
         bad_alignment* ref_count = ptr-sizeof(bad_alignment);
         if (--*ref_count == 0) //if no more pointing at this block
             free(ptr);
      }         
 }
```

If you have threads, you'll have to add locks to all that.  My C is rusty and the code is untested, so do a lot of research on these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is slightly more difficult, since your code is straightforward, but... what if another pointer is made to point to the same place as x?

```
// generated C code.
int main() {
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
    int *y = x;
    *x = 5;
    free(x); // inserted by the compiler, now wrong 
}
```

You doubtlessly will have a heap structure, in which each block has a header that tells a) whether the block is in use, and b) the size of the block. This can be achieved with a small structure, or by using the highest bit for a) in the integer value for b) [is this a 64bit compiler or 32bit?]. For simplicity, lets consider:

```
typedef struct {
    bool allocated: 1;
    size_t size;
} BlockHeader;
```

You would have to add another field to that small structure, which would be a reference count. Each time a pointer points to that block in the heap, you increment the reference count. When a pointer stops pointing to a block, then its reference count is decremented. If it reaches 0, then it can be compacted or whatever. The use of the `allocated` field has now gone.

```
typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    size_t referenceCount;
} BlockHeader;
```

[Reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) is quite simple to implement, but comes with a down side: it means there is overhead each time the value of a pointer changes. Still, is the simplest scheme to work, and that's why some programming languages still use it, such as Python.

Comment: If the output is C, he doesn't need to have a heap structure

Comment: I was trying to answer the question from the OP, and for that I made assumptions, such as the use of a heap structure.

Comment: I see that.  The question is why did you make that assumption?  I see no reason to make that assumption, and can list several reasons that your assumption is improbable.